# purpose of text-overflow:clip value?

Tags: css

Why supply `text-overflow:clip` CSS if it appears to behave the exact same way without supplying it and just using `overflow:hidden` with `white-space:no-wrap` (which `text-overflow` requires anyway)?

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/johntrepreneur/0pae4h0s/)

Answer (score 0):

It's its default property, so every div will have it.
If not declared, the default is `text-overflow: clip`